# Skip last line with Sybase BCP

Tags: sybase, bcp

I have a file with the last line like this:

```
[End of File]
```

Can I read all the lines before it and skip this one without getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off creating a script to remove that line.

The only way for that line not to cause issues would be to set the bcp in batch size to 1 (`-b1`) Depending on how much data you are working with, using a batch size of 1 will take a long time to finish.